# Socket or HTTP requests

Tags: c++, sockets, http, networking

In my organization I have multiple computers and I need to program a software that follow instructions from a server. The use of the program is to monitor and detect problems remotely. So I need the clients listen for instructions, and I can't decide whether use socket that make the communication instant and "real-time", but the down side is it's take process resources OR use HTTP request to check on the DB if there is a new instructions, but the down side is that the communication have a delay because the client make a request let's say every 1.5min

Any suggestions?

Comment: Opinion: I'd start with the server pushing status to the listener and profile to see if it really does have an impact.

Comment: 10x I'll do that

Answer (score 0):

If you mean direct requests to DB from client side, this is not a good solution. Depending on machines count, database will be bottleneck at one time. That's why client-server solution will be preferred. Another ways to obtain requests in realtime (if direct socket connection may have problem, but HTTP is OK):

1. HTTP long polling
2. websockets